# TypeScript Generic that ensures Record key match

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I am attempting to author a `class` that will give me type safety for each `key + value` specified in an `interface` and passed as a `generic`.

I've managed to get everything working EXCEPT that I am unable to ensure that a `key` belongs to the `interface`. On other words: I can pass `string` values that ARE NOT found within the `interface` provided to a `generic`.

I just cannot figure out how to adjust my code so that I can guarantee the  `key` exists in the `interface`.

An ultra-minimal version of the code:

```
type Listener<V = unknown[]> = (...values: V[]) => void;
type EventMap = Record<string, Listener>;

type Library<T> = Partial<Record<keyof T, Set<T[keyof T]>>>;

class EventBlaster<T extends EventMap> {
  lib: Library<T> = {};

  register<K extends keyof T>(eventName: K, listener: T[K]) {}
  trigger<K extends keyof T>(eventName: K, ...values: Parameters<T[K]>) {}
}

///
/// Usage

type CustomMap = EventMap & {
  change(value: string): void;
};

const customEvents = new EventBlaster<CustomMap>();

// Working register / trigger

customEvents.register('change', (value) => {});
customEvents.trigger('change', 'hello');

// TypeScript correctly throwing errors on wrong listener arguments

customEvents.trigger('change', '1st string', '2nd string');

// TypeScript failing to throw errors on undeclared event names

customEvents.register('nope', () => {});
customEvents.trigger('nope');
```

In that example, I've got all of the `listener > argument values` working as expected - which is great and I assumed that would be the hard part...

But unfortunately, you can see that I am able to call `register / trigger` with `string` values that are not `keys` on the `CustomMap` type.

Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated! It would also be great if I didn't have to `extend EventMap` every time I defined a `interface` to provide as the `generic` argument for `EventBlaster`... but my assumption is that this is a requirement to get the behaviour that I am after.

A slightly more robust example of the code can be found in [this TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQiwCgWACAVBPADgUwM4QgFyc6BRAN2QDtMBpZeaAXmlUwCcBLYgc2gB874BbAIwD2AGwDcWHNAAyTeiWQMAPADUa0AK7EA1sQEB3YgG0AugD5VACgB01ggEMhatAC5oS4wEoaZggKYATMXBsFHwiUgBZW0RVACVkAGMBBj8FQhJySgAaKRlMOQYTQPEQ6T4GWwZ4BVgzWjjE5IVNSgEAMzhsgGVkTGqDZvg2uFNC4txS8sqABQrMJntq2ugZhjmFiYqqmtHwCCg9kGgAYSFbVFRoP2RWliY5gWIMcHjT89D0gCFXvMVYaGQAB55Yh%20C5pCJRMwAbwg0GgQiYfBcG2ms3mQkWqihAF8iuA4QxkKxcvIFGR-kCSKDoAMhjVzMgwpgAHK2HjIFxkbII2TEeQuWAGMhGTww-Fw6BMdrmTAACxklgRfAMjPSrPZRhotGIaiEQlFsIlcLlCqVKqZ6uQmu1yF00G6mHM7kCRuxTyNJtQisR5rVbKtAH5LLY-H5zDzgfJnYa3btxYwmKxWKTyYDgdTae16arSJbOdlrJY7A5nMsKv6fqg%20sKTAbxXDEsR6NAeLq5g7VJ7vcqcyz-UY8UbW0J2z0g60knhbPFZeZwyS%20QxPNRoYajRH8lYbPZHKho-XoNj93DY7GDsBz9AAKqoWzJp7BXBHNT0AQ8SLRWjgzAf6AAMmgMUG1lWw2GQcxi0cFx6GYNh3BcHx-BdaBEg0R1IOQAMXB1fgowQ3wAkNRI9QSR1CQARzUJhCT8aCEzYAtrAERB7mIew6Ng1gPHwpDDR0E02CdHjCPAXEnkbZt4hfTA32-C4bTtb8vjOH4FGfV930hJ08UOAB1JJNBYdhCWJWQGGgGAEyTeRxOk2SmS9EySQYcwAHIZ1A5NXOyCCd2QZdoSPQIpI0uTLCcsy3NQ0hvOgXySwCwCgogEKZJ4MKIp%20KLhCEUjYvMCiqJoxjLGY1j7ESnF91S%20z0kcolnLc-j5TYfLKuSuMavShzLCs5MXPckCwNi1zZWQPUBFc6q7O6ureuYayBuizApuCmawr6%20RsrQ2KAEZptCnrNqWnK8uyVzdubGCjJGgAmEE6Ho1gRoAZmSR7ONWlL1qOhb%20qagQBOe-cDjgHBOniZgWJQpJCXiTAhCoOUGD0Iz-gYFGGAuB5oF0FG2HhBd5GgCpWDUdlSHQTqfrm46oqGrzzsuzAPpu877r8VnWoOtKNr%20rb3IEHbskYRwedqyn5sTf7BZI%20GvueGnJbp1zmrZ6BXNQN8eha4GdJgBAUAhqGWdaWwmARAmZOgZG9HRzHseIdQQQSU4aP%20JloDY9kqe%20w65sygWdBQNqvCS8XZuV-mBuD5AFaAA).

Comment: Don't intersect your custom map with `EventMap`? https://tsplay.dev/WG4o0w

Comment: @vera thank you so much! Your suggestion is exactly what worked! What I was overlooking all this time was the: `V extends readonly unknown[] = any[]`

It is interesting that I cannot use `interface` when defining my `EventMap`, and must use `type` instead. I would have thought that - as long as I wasn't extending - the two would be treated identically.

I have pushed your suggestion to my "TS event emitter" package and it is working perfectly:
https://github.com/beefchimi/emitten

I am very grateful for your help! If you post your suggestion as an answer, I will select it as "correct".

Comment: Deleted my answer as it was incorrect and I don't have time to correct it.